# Dx11: how to handler a large number of Textures

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11

I have to load about 600 different textures, and a texture is 4096 x 4096. These textures should be updated by frame which means I need to load at least half of them at the same time.My laptop's memory is 8G, so when I test the game, computer is very laggy and memory is almost used up.What can I do to handler the problem? Thank for all replies！

The function used to load texture is

```
CreateWICTextureFromFile
```

And file format is "png".
Any reply would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Loading 600 4K textures at 32bpp would require 37.5GiB of RAM. There is no reasonable way that you're going to keep all of those textures resident. You're going to have to stream the data in just before it is needed.

Comment: @vandench Can you tell me more about how to do "stream data"?Thank you very much!

Comment: @vandench it should even be 1.5x that size, since 4k by 4k need mipmaps to be displayed properly, there's no way a game would only sample level 0 on all those textures in a single frame. BC compression would reduce that amount by a 8x factor or 4x factor but still huge indeed.